# Did spacing increase recently?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, formatting

Yesterday I noticed that line spacing in questions & answers is bigger than before, something like 1.5

[image]

Is there some global change, or is it a bug? Or maybe I do have a bug or something?
Can I control line spacing on the site in some easy way?
Not that it is intolerable but still it would be good to know if I can change it.

Comment: [meta.se]: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446) (and some of the [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/353446) might be of interest, too).

Comment: @Martin Many thanks as always! So, there is no way back?

Comment: You've been around long enough to know that SO tells you what you want—sorry, nowadays, they listen to you, *then* tell you what you want—and that mass user discontent is of no concern.

Comment: @LSpice Richard Stallman said that Facebook doesn't have "users", but only "useds". Is StackOverflow moving in the same direction?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're right, line spacing has been increased, as mentioned here on Meta Stack Exchange: [New post formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353446/295232)

Many people don't like the change, and posts like [Please revert the line-height change!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353525/295232) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353529/295232) are very popular right now. Stack Exchange has [already reduced the line-height a bit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353561/295232) from their original intention.

There is no setting in your profile to turn it back to the old style, but [somebody already wrote a userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353542/295232) (some kind of browser extension) which does.